# Go: Execute SCP command and print output

Tags: go, scp

I am trying to run an `scp` command using the `CMD` struct in Go's `os/exec`. The output should be printed to the console while the command is running. My problem is with the latter, I can't seem to get the output in the console.

I have created the following functions to handle this:

```golang
func ExecCommand(cmd *exec.Cmd, errorMsg string) {
    stdOut, _ := cmd.StdoutPipe()
    stdErr, _ := cmd.StderrPipe()
    if err := cmd.Start(); err != nil {
        printError(fmt.Sprintf("%v\n%v", errorMsg, err))
    }
    PrintExecCommandOutput(stdOut, false)
    PrintExecCommandOutput(stdErr, true)
    if err := cmd.Wait(); err != nil {
        printError("Command did not finish")
    }
}

func PrintExecCommandOutput(reader io.Reader, isError bool) {
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(reader)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        if isError {
            printNonPanicErr(scanner.Text())
        } else {
            fmt.Println(scanner.Text())
        }
    }
}
```

This works fine for running other commands and printing their outputs, but not for `scp`.
Is there a way to get `scp`'s output printed in the console using Go?

Comment: Just go guide you in the right direction; it's not that go fails to capture stdout, it's that `scp` detects it dosn't have an interactive terminal and disables interactive output is has, which wouldn't be nice when redirected. It behaves the same if you do `scp file target: > log.txt`.